# boost::graph: How to remove in-edges of a previously removed vertex?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I created the simplest directed graph possible using boost::graph, and added 2 vertices that are mutually connected via 2 edges.

After removing the first vertex, the second vertex still has an out-edge that points to the previously removed vertex.

```
boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::directedS,
    boost::no_property,
    boost::no_property
>  graph;

// add 2 vertices and connect them
auto v0 = boost::add_vertex(graph);
auto v1 = boost::add_vertex(graph);

boost::add_edge(v0, v1, graph);
boost::add_edge(v1, v0, graph);

// remove the first vertex
boost::remove_vertex(v0, graph); 

// iterate over vertices and print their out_degree. 
auto [begin, end] = boost::vertices(graph);

for (auto vertex_itr = begin; vertex_itr != end; ++vertex_itr)
{
    auto vertex_descriptor = *vertex_itr;

    auto out_degree = boost::out_degree(vertex_descriptor, graph);

    std::cout << out_degree << '\n'; // this prints 1
}
```

To my understanding, my graph is in a sort of "invalid state" where an edge points to a non exiting vertex.
From further examining, it seems as if the "dangling edge" has become an edge with `source == target`. This makes me even more confused as to why boost::graph decided to leave this edge and even go to the trouble of making it cyclic.

Questions:

- How do I fix this?
- How do I remove the in edges of a vertex?
- Does it make more sense to use a bidirectional graph in this situation?

Also, I couldn't find anything on the docs regarding this behavior, so I would appreciate if someone could point me to the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation isn't "going through the trouble" - it's just doing anything, because [you didn't satisfy the pre-conditions](https://cs.brown.edu/%7Ejwicks/boost/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html#:%7E:text=It%20is%20assumed%20that%20there%20are%20no%20edges%20to%20or%20from%20vertex%20u%20when%20it%20is%20removed):

> `void remove_vertex(vertex_descriptor u, adjacency_list& g)`
>
> Remove vertex u from the vertex set of the graph. **It is assumed that there are no edges to or from vertex u when it is removed.** One way to make sure of this is to invoke `clear_vertex()` beforehand.

I repro-ed your issue slightly more briefly: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c44c689c308835a4)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> g(2);

    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(1, 0, g);

    print_graph(g, std::cout << "--- Before: ");
        
    remove_vertex(0, g); // remove the first vertex

    print_graph(g, std::cout << "--- After: ");

    // iterate over vertices and print their out_degree. 
    for (auto [it, end] = boost::vertices(g); it != end; ++it)
        std::cout << out_degree(*it, g) << "\n"; // this prints 1
}
```

Prints

```
--- Before: 0 --> 1 
1 --> 0 
--- After: 0 --> 0 
1
```

---

### Fixing It

Let's simply do as the docs say:

```
clear_vertex(0, g);  // clear edges
remove_vertex(0, g); // remove the first vertex
```

Now it works: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adc5ddab6b1d5f22)**, printing:

```
--- Before: 0 --> 1 
1 --> 0 
--- After: 0 --> 
0
```

#### BONUS

For [more elegance](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a7f011a13daf19e):

```
// iterate over vertices and print their out_degree. 
for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
    std::cout << v << " out_degree: " << out_degree(v, g) << "\n";
```